# not a valid phone number

Tags: phone-number

Need help in identifying what is the issue and how to overcome this. Below is the error I am currently facing. I am trying to register an available domain in Route53 through AWS Javascript API in nodejs 6. It is saying the phone number is not valid. But I have used the same phone number from aws route53 console, and same phone number gets accepted. I tried by changing the format of the phone like removing "." , moving it etc. But it gives another error:

```
"ADMIN.PHONE: '+02266XX4811' does not resemble +999.12345678"
```

---

{ [TLDRulesViolation: [ADMIN.PHONE: '+022.66XX4800' is not a valid phone number, OWNER.PHONE: '+022.66XX4800' is not a valid phone number, TECH.PHONE: '+022.66XX4800' is not a valid phone number, BILL.PHONE: '+022.66XX4800' is not a valid phone number]]
  message: '[ADMIN.PHONE: \'+022.66XX4800\' is not a valid phone number, OWNER.PHONE: \'+022.66XX4800\' is not a valid phone number, TECH.PHONE: \'+022.66XX4800\' is not a valid phone number, BILL.PHONE: \'+022.66XX4800\' is not a valid phone number]',
  code: 'TLDRulesViolation',
  time: Thu Oct 19 2017 12:32:28 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  requestId: '91f5ca3e-b4c9-11e7-b0c2-a34579169cee',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,

```
Below is the code I am using:

route53domains.registerDomain(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        console.log("error");
    }else{
        console.log(data);           // successful response
```

})

params :

```
    { "regjson" : {
        "AutoRenew": false,
        "DomainName": "testingdomxxx.com",
        "DurationInYears": 1,
        "AdminContact": { 
          "AddressLine1": "900",
          "AddressLine2": "Skyline",
          "City": "Mumbai",
          "ContactType": "PERSON",
          "CountryCode": "IN",
          "Email": "testingdomain@gmail.com",
          "Fax": "02228573244",
          "FirstName": "testname",
          "LastName": "testname",
          "OrganizationName": "Skyline",
          "PhoneNumber": "+022.66XX4800",
          "State": "MA",
          "ZipCode": "400079"
       },
       "RegistrantContact": { 
          "AddressLine1": "900",
          "AddressLine2": "Skyline",
          "City": "Mumbai",
          "ContactType": "PERSON",
          "CountryCode": "IN",
          "Email": "testingdomain@gmail.com",
          "Fax": "02228573244",
          "FirstName": "testname",
          "LastName": "testname",
          "OrganizationName": "Skyline",
          "PhoneNumber": "+022.66XX4800",
          "State": "MA",
          "ZipCode": "400079"
       },
       "TechContact": { 
          "AddressLine1": "900",
          "AddressLine2": "Skyline",
          "City": "Mumbai",
          "ContactType": "PERSON",
          "CountryCode": "IN",
          "Email": "testingdomain@gmail.com",
          "Fax": "02228573244",
          "FirstName": "testname",
          "LastName": "testname",
          "OrganizationName": "Skyline",
          "PhoneNumber": "+022.66XX4800",
          "State": "MA",
          "ZipCode": "400079"
       }
    }
}
```

(Two digits have been masked in phone number for confidentiality, but while sending, it is digits and not XX)
I have to do this in Lambda but facing same error in both lambda and nodejs. Anybody has any idea, what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Could it be that that number is not a valid phone number in India and your `CountryCode` is India?

Comment: I have used a valid phone number only. I have no idea why they expect the dot(.). My country code is India and it is a valid phone number I have used. Still I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out that it is of the format +91.9966XX4800
The dot comes after the country code and is required. I had to register one domain through the route53 console and see the phone number shown there. Used the same format and worked. Thanks all for all your help, appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

India phone numbers in international format start with `+91`.

I think the correct phone number should be `+91 2266X X4800` (or `+912266XX4800` without spaces).

Comment: +1 for +0. :) It is not actually North America (which is really +1) but rather the 0 prefix appears to reflect the dialing pattern used when calling non-local within India.  +91 followed by 10 digits should indeed be correct.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I tried that already, it was not accepting that either. Thats the issue. +022  I used is the landline code and +91 is for cellular.

Comment: Hi @dashmug, as mentioned earlier, if . is not present, I get [ADMIN.PHONE: '+912266XX4800' does not resemble +999.12345678,

Comment: Tried with another country phone number also, still facing the same issue. I am starting to doubt if the AWS API for domain registration is working!

Comment: It's definitely working for me in Australia. You have to find someone from India.

Comment: Can you please share the payload json you are using, I am doubting if I am not doing anything silly. I would try with some similar data and with your country code. The domain I would register would be ephemeral, am using it for testing only. Or optionally, can you have a look into my payload above and check the difference with your data..